# Calculating the standard error for the ratio of 2 random variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, standard-error, intuition

I have 2 40x10 matrices, $X$ and $Y$. Each row represents a sample, and each column represents a different trial. Its OK to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are random normal variables if that's relevant.

I need to calculate the standard deviation for each trial in $X$ and $Y$, and then I must take the ratio of the means of these standard deviations, i.e., I need $R = mean(\sigma_{x_i})/mean(\sigma_{y_i})$, where $i$ denotes each trial.

This quantity is obviously easy to compute but I've also been asked to calculate the standard error for $R$, however, I'm not sure how to do this. Should I calculate $r_i = \sigma_{x_i}/\sigma_{y_i}$, and then take the standard error of $r_i$? My intuition is that the quantity $mean(r_i)$ is biased compared to $R$, but I'm not sure if that's relevant for calculating the standard error.